# How to get a list of friends that uses the same app and can be tagged in one Graph API request only?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile

Our mobile app wants to offer the functionality of allowing a user to post an invite with friends mentions in the message, but we only want to display a list of the friend users that currently have the app installed too. The user will be able to type their preferred message and then select the users to mention.

The Graph Api offers the endpoint for getting a list of friends that have the app installed `/me/friends?fields=installed` and with `/{user-id}/taggable_friends` you get a list of all your friends that allows tagging/mentioning.

Is there a way to obtain the list of all the taggable friends that have authorized our app?

We are developing our app using Titanium Studio and their Facebook module, we're using Titanium SDK 3.2.0.GA and deploying for Android and iOS.

Comment: I can be wrong but it sounds like pre-fill. Make sure you read https://developers.facebook.com/policy .

Comment: The user will write the message, what we want to do is to display only the list of users that also use the same app, because it has no use to post an invite on the timeline with user mentions that aren't currently using the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the user have to select people to tag too.

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question, the app won't be the one responsible for selecting which mentions are posted, we only want to show a filtered list of all the people that are currently friends with the user and have the app installed, the user doesn't want to see people who aren't using the app.

Comment: well it seems what our client wanted created a conflict a conflict with Facebook policies, Facebook team told us directly it wasn't allowed said behaviour. If you would like to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.